# JavaScript Gmail client library with existing token

Tags: javascript, gmail, gmail-api

How can I initialize javascript Gmail API library with OAuth tokens I have? 
The only method I can find is to use client_id, like here:

```
gapi.auth.authorize(
{
   'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
   'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
   'immediate': true
}, handleAuthResult);
```

But how to initialize Gmail client library if I already have the token?

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by you have already the token ? you mean you have the access token  ?

If you have already have the access token you could just send requests to Gmail API follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/) by adding this header to requests:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + acessToken);
```

If you don't have this access token so could you tell what to what you mean ? with gapi.auth.authorize you just need the client id and then you could load the library you want and send  in 'handleAuthResult'

Comment: I'm using direct API calls now. Just wanted to know how can I use client library with an existing token to minimize code changes.

Comment: If you want to use client library I think that you don't need token  , in 'handleAuthResult' you just load your library and create request to gmail api...
`gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', function(){ ....... create your request here});`